# What characteristics are generally considered traits for perfection?

Tags: sociology

Assuming it's possible for someone to be absolutely perfect, can we get an idea of what is socially considered "perfect" (in a manner or way that could not be better) through linguistics?

For example, the following phrases seem quite common:
"perfectly elegant" "perfectly willing" "perfectly flexible"

All of these phrases can be used in the context of "in a manner or way that could not be better."

But instead of saying "perfectly powerful," the following phrase is more common:
"absolutely powerful"

Does that mean power is never perfect? And if the phrase "perfectly powerful" is never used, does that mean the general public thinks power isn't a positive trait?

P.S. Can you complete the list of traits socially considered to be necessary for absolute perfection and the list of traits that aren't necessary?

Comment: 'perfectly despicable', could be an equivocation. not sure! if not, it doesn't easily well with 'morally perfect'. strange, that perfection doesn't fit well with 'power'

Comment: I guess there, it's a different meaning of perfect, maybe "completely." But "perfectly" not fitting well with power makes me think that none of the definitions of perfect fits power.

Comment: "not qualified or diminished in any way; total" cf "in a manner or way that could not be better." maybe we tend to assume in everyday language that power itself is not good; or ironically perfect either. i'm not sure if this is a (raw) philosophy question, or not. buddhism has the six perfections, don't know anything analogous outside that

Comment: Yea, but there is not a sociology SE, so I thought this forum included sociology.

Comment: "*Questions on the definitions or semantics of words or phrases are off-topic here as they are already well-answered elsewhere*", e.g. in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfection), another possibility is to ask on English SE. "Perfection" was used in a technical sense in medieval scholastic philosophy, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/transcendentals-medieval/#ThiModBeiUniComGodCreDunSco), but your question is not about that, apparently.

Comment: I’m not asking for the definition of perfection, but the traits that are considered part of it? How is that linguistics? What definition did I ask for?

Comment: "Perfectly round" and "perfectly square" would comprise very different and _exclusive_ "traits", this question doesn't make much sense from this perspective. All that remains seems to be: the difference between "power" and "elegant, willing, flexible"

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!

The Sanskrit word "purnam", also the Latin "plenum", are often source/target translations for English "perfect". Purnam is evoked in a widely cited vedic mantra :

> Om! purnam ada purnam idam purnat purnam udachyate
>   Purnasya purnam adaya purnam evava shishyate Om!

A quasi-translation would be :

> O!
>   That (transcendental reality – God) is purnam.
>   This (mundane reality) is (also) purnam.
>   From that purnam this purnam (came/comes/generated – tense ambiguous).
>   When you take away the purnam from the purnam the purnam alone remains!
>   O!!

The difficulty in this translation is of course the untranslated "purnam".

- One can render it as "whole" "complete" etc.
- One can equally render it as "the Infinite"
- And one can render it as "perfect"

Note the first two are in obvious contradiction :
A whole is defined, de-**limited**
The infinite is unlimited (and in most math) undefined

"Perfect" carries that contradiction in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Natural languages are full of idioms and conventions that have little or no philosophical significance. For instance, it is true that 'perfectly powerful' is not idiomatic; we are more likely to say 'X has absolute power' or 'X is omnipotent'. ('Absolutely powerful' is not idiomatic, incidentally; the relevant idioms are those I've just indicated.) However, this is just a quirk of natural language. The following is an example in which 'perfectly powerful' is used with full philosophical justification and in which its lack of idiomatic currency is irrelevant:

> The concept of God is the concept of a maximally powerful perfect being,
>    a being who, among other impressive attributes, has the maximal degree of
>    power it is possible (in a broadly logical or metaphysical sense) to exemplify.
>    God is thus ajperfect being who is **perfectly powerful**. To specify this further,
>    the traditional theist typically makes three claims. First, there are and can be
>    no independent, externally determined constraints on divine power. Secondly, the internally determined structure and scope of God's abilities to act
>    (those parameters on divine action set by his own nature and activity) are
>    not, and cannot be, such that he lacks any possible ability or power it is
>    intrinsically better to have than to lack. And finally, God is the sole source
>    and continuous support of all the power there is or could be. Thus, no individual can possibly exemplify or exercize any ability, capacity or power
>    whose existence does not ultimately derive from God.

(Thomas V. Morris, 'Perfection and Power', International Journal for Philosophy of Religion, Vol. 20, No. 2/3 (1986), pp. 165-
168: 166.)